# Converting NSString to array of chars inside For Loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsstring, char

I'm trying to use an existing piece of code in an iOS project to alphabetize a list of words in an array (for instance, to make tomato into amoott, or stack into ackst). The code seems to work if I run it on its own, but I'm trying to integrate it into my existing app.

Each word I want it to alphabetize is stored as an NSString inside an array. The issue seems to be that the code takes the word as an array of chars, and I can't get my NSStrings into that format.

If I use `string = [currentWord UTFString]`, I get an error of `Array type char[128] is not assignable`, and if I try to create the char array inside the loop (`const char *string = [curentWord UTF8String]`) I get warnings relating to `Initializing char with type const char discards qualifiers`. Not quite sure how I can get around it – any tips? The method is below, I'll take care of storing the alphabetized versions later.

```
- (void) alphabetizeWord {
    char string[128], temp;
    int n, i, j;

    for (NSString* currentWord in wordsList) {
        n = [currentWord length];
        for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
                if (string[i] > string[j]) {
                    temp = string[i];
                    string[i] = string[j];
                    string[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"The word %@ in alphabetical order is %s", currentWord, string);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you currently have an array of NSString, and you want an array of char* ?

Comment: I think so, yes. Tricky to see which part isn't working, but the NSString in the array isn't getting into `string` at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
- (void)alphabetizeWord {
  char str[128];

  for (NSString *currentWord in wordList)
  {
    int wordLength = [currentWord length];
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
    {
      str[i] = [currentWord characterAtIndex:i];
    }
    // Adding the termination char
    str[wordLength] = 0;
    // Add your word
  }
}
```

EDIT : Sorry, didn't fully understand at first. Gonna check this out.

Comment: Nope, you win, seems to have worked by combining my existing code with what you've given here!