# Objective-C: Splitting a word into an array of characters

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, nsstring, nsarray

Sorry for the rather simple question but I'm pretty new to objective-c and can't seem to find a solution to my problem that actually works with what i'm trying to do.
Essentially, I have a NSString containing the a random word.
For example:

```
NSString *word = @"Characters";
```

I then want to take this and split it into an array consisting of the characters so that I can index each of them:

```
[0] C
[1] H
[2] A
```

etc

It's not really important if after they're split if they're put into a NSString or an Array, as long as I can separate the string into each off the individual characters then index them.

Also for clarification, the word isn't hard coded it's randomly generated every time my program runs and pulled from a word list.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are *many, many* [caveats](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html) to string processing. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `getCharacters:range:`

Comment: Check out this answer here. Basically you just have to loop through it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13359464/834310

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder That's not really necessary.  If you just need to access characters based on their index, my answer will suffice.  If you need an array, HotLicks's comment will handle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to do this.  Internally, the string already is an array of characters, and you can access the individual characters by index...

```
[word characterAtIndex:2] // returns 'a'
```

Comment: Right. The only gotcha is that `'a'` is a `unichar` (`unsigned short`), and you might want to wrap it back into a `NSString`.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[word characterAtIndex:i]];` if you really need it.

Comment: Not the only gotcha. A Unichar can be any valid UTF16 code point. That includes whitespace, control characters, unassigned characters, combining characters etc. You need to check characterSet membership and consider normalization forms based on what you intend to do with the character strings.

Comment: The question is about how to get a character at a specific index, which this answer sufficiently answers.  The question is not how to get a character at an index and then make sure it's a specific sort of character.  The downvote is really unacceptable and needs a much better explanation given the actual question...

Answer (score 0):

#### Update Swift 4+

Default you have a string

```
let string = "Characters"
```

so, all you need to do is...

```
for i:Int in 0..< string.count {
     let char = NSString(format: "%c", (string as NSString).character(at: i))
     print(char) //Optionally you can convert using 'char as String'
}
```

Note:- this is the update for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22976405/4131763)